# Merge two columns of a dataframe into an already existing column of dictionaries as a key value pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

If we have 3 columns of a dataframe as :

```
column1 : ['A','A','B','C']
column2 : [12,13,14,15]
column3 : [{"key1":"val1"},{"key2":"val2"},{"key3":"val3"},{"key4":"val4"}]
```

I want the column3 to be something like :

```
column3 : [{"key1":"val1", "A":12},{"key2":"val2", "A":13},{"key3":"val3", "B":14},{"key4":"val4", "C":15}]
```

I have tried a  few things from using lambda functions with apply to iterating over rows but all were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension and unpacking as:

```
df['col3'] = [{**d, k:v} for k,v,d in df.values.tolist()]
```

---

```
print(df)

  col1  col2                       col3
0    A    12  {'key1': 'val1', 'A': 12}
1    A    13  {'key2': 'val2', 'A': 13}
2    B    14  {'key3': 'val3', 'B': 14}
3    C    15  {'key4': 'val4', 'C': 15}
```

---

Input data -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','B','C'], 
                   'col2':[12,13,14,15],
                   'col3':[{"key1":"val1"},{"key2":"val2"},
                           {"key3":"val3"},{"key4":"val4"}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of apply and lambda function. It goes like this:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.column3.update({row.column1: row.column2}), axis=1)
```

So the output would be:

```
  column1  column2                    column3
0       A       12  {'key1': 'val1', 'A': 12}
1       A       13  {'key2': 'val2', 'A': 13}
2       B       14  {'key3': 'val3', 'B': 14}
3       C       15  {'key4': 'val4', 'C': 15}
```